# PHP PDO with 2 inner joins. How to differentiate between them in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi i have the following code.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $get_member_data = $conn->prepare("SELECT T.trip_id, T.trip_destination, T.trip_leaderid, T.trip_driverid, T.trip_datedeperting, T.trip_datereturning, T.trip_timedeperting, T.trip_timereturning, L.member_surname, D.member_surname FROM trip AS T INNER JOIN members AS L ON L.member_id = T.trip_leaderid INNER JOIN members AS D ON D.member_id = T.trip_driverid");
    $get_member_data->execute();
    while( $row = $get_member_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_destination']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['L.member_surname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['D.member_surname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_datedeperting']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_datereturning']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_timedeperting']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_timereturning'];?></td>
</tr>
```

trying to grab 2 separate members surnames and display on the same table row. with this code i get no surnames displayed. if i get rid of the L. and D. it just displayed the second members name twice.

Comment: You need SQL aliases: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set 2 different columns in your query like `L.member_surname l_member_surname, D.member_surname d_member_surname,` where `l_member_surname` and `d_member_surname` are new column names. And call those columns in your php code later:

```
    <td><?php echo $row['l_member_surname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['d_member_surname']; ?></td>
```

So your code would be:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $get_member_data = $conn->prepare("SELECT T.trip_id, T.trip_destination, T.trip_leaderid, T.trip_driverid, T.trip_datedeperting, T.trip_datereturning, T.trip_timedeperting, T.trip_timereturning, L.member_surname l_member_surname, D.member_surname d_member_surname FROM trip AS T INNER JOIN members AS L ON L.member_id = T.trip_leaderid INNER JOIN members AS D ON D.member_id = T.trip_driverid");
    $get_member_data->execute();
    while( $row = $get_member_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_destination']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['l_member_surname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['d_member_surname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_datedeperting']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_datereturning']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_timedeperting']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trip_timereturning'];?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows you to alias selected fields:

```
SELECT ... , L.member_surname AS `somealias1`, D.member_surname AS `somealias2`...
```